# Find an object in a Realm using BETWEEN

Tags: swift3, realm

I am using Realm object as shown below and created a database of the objects. I also created a function to find an element based on current time. I am having difficulty in creating the predicate this function needs. I am using a format as defined in the Realm cheatsheet, but I'm getting an exception as follows:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid predicate', reason:
>   'Predicate with BETWEEN operator must compare a KeyPath with an
>   aggregate with two values'

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

func composeUniqueRealmPrimaryKeyForWorkorder(_ start:String) -> String {
    return start
}

class WorkorderRecord: Object {

    dynamic var id = ""
    dynamic var workorder = ""
    dynamic var start = "" // defines start time string as in 2017-06-09 9:00
    dynamic var end = "" // defines end of interval as in 2017-06-10 16:30


    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    override class func indexedProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["workorder","start","end"]
    }

    convenience init(_ workorder:String, start:String, end:String) {
        self.init()
        self.id = composeUniqueRealmPrimaryKeyForWorkorder (workorder)
        self.workorder = workorder
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
    }
}

func getValueForInterval(time:String) -> String? {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%@ BETWEEN {start , end }", time)
    let r = realm.objects(WorkorderRecord.self).filter(predicate)
    if r.count == 0 {
        print("NO RECORD FOUND")
        return ""
    } else {
        let workorder = r[0].workorder
        let start = r[0].start
        let end = r[0].end
        print("RECORD Retrieved: workorder= \(workorder) start= \(start) end= \(end)")
        return workorder
    }
}
```

Comment: The between predicate from Realm CheatSheet is like that : [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"expenses BETWEEN {200, 400}"] and from what i can see in your code it is like that : time(whatever value) BETWEEN {start,end}. I think start and end should have real values

Comment: I agree with your statement but I would like to find a record which falls between "start" and "end" which are fields on each record. Any ideas on how to create an appropriate predicate?

Comment: than you have to provide actual value for start and end just like you are doing for time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you reason about what semantics the `BETWEEN` operator provides, you'll soon realize that `foo BETWEEN {bar, baz}` is equivalent to `foo >= bar AND foo <= baz`[0]. While Realm currently supports only constant values in the `{bar, baz}` aggregate expression, there's no such restriction on normal relational comparison operators.

One sticking point you'll run into is that while Realm supports comparison operators such as `>=` and `<=` on numeric and `Date` types, they are not currently supported on string types. Since you're storing your start and end times as strings, you're not able to take advantage of this transformation without further changes.

If you switch to storing your times using the `Date` type, you'll be able to reformulate your query as:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%@ >= start AND %@ <= end", time, time)
```

This would also have the advantage of reducing the space required to store the dates.

[0]: Note that this is only true if the key path `foo` does not traverse any to-many relationships. If it does traverse to-many relationships, a `SUBQUERY` is needed to match `BETWEEN`s semantics.

Comment: Thank you for a clear explanation and for editing my question. It is so much more clear now. I now have to work on finding the time interval just ahead of the time.